# Term for "altering passed-in variable"?

Tags: functional-programming, immutability, idempotent

Is there a term for the style of programming where you pass in an object, add data to the object, and return the same object? Like so:

```
public Person getAddressInfo(Person person) {
    Address address = lookupAddressInDB(person.getId());
    person.setAddress(address);
    return person;
}
```

This is not my favorite way of doing things if it can be avoided because it can be harder to refactor. Is there a name for this (sometimes anti-)pattern? I want to say that it's "not idempotent" or "mutable-argumented", but I don't think those terms are correct.

Is there a name for this?